# How to get the baseURL in a Typo3 template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I defined with typoscript the baseURL with the following code:

```
page.config.baseURL = http://www.website.nl/
```

Now I want to use the baseURL in the html template for a reference to a image. How can I add this url to the template? Tried the following but is not working.

```
<img src="{baseURL}images/sicma.png" width="70" height="28" alt="sicma">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into a constant first:

```
baseURL = http://www.website.nl/
```

then use it in setup

```
page.config.baseURL = {$baseURL}

temp.logo = TEXT
temp.logo.value = <img src="{$baseURL}images/sicma.png" width="70" height="28" alt="sicma">
```

Of course, you have to assign temp.logo to the template.

But isn't baseURL precisely there so you don't have to write absolute paths?

Comment: You are right. Using the baseurl feature **and** an absolute path is redundant.